# How to set up www directory to public? WAMP

Tags: mysql, apache, server, wampserver, remote-access

I cant seem to find any good solution for my issue so I hope this question will be answered once and for all.
First, I understand that by hosting my html files online directly from my PC means to loosen up my PC security and that can be dangerous. But I am fine with this as this is just my testing laptop. Nothing important or whatsoever in here.

So lets start with the main issue. I have port forwarded the port 3306, 80, 8080, and 2727(which I plan to switch the apache port to this)

Tested port online and result is open.

In my apache **httpd.conf** file, here is what I have setup..

**Listen 0.0.0.0:2727**

**ServerName xxx.xxx.x.xx:2727** (which is my private ip)

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">

Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
Allow from all
Order Allow,Deny

AllowOverride All
Require all granted

</Directory>
```

I am now able to access my **index.html** in the wamp www directory by typing **127.0.0.1:2727** in the url (same goes to /phpmyadmin)

What should I do next to make sure my public ip can access the **index.html**?
Example, when I enter my public ip like this **175.162.154.18:2727**, it just shows connection timed out.

Extra info if this helps :

1. My WAMP is orange.
2. I have the MYSQL Community Edition in my PC.
3. My WAMP version is 2.5
4. Apache version is 2.4.9
5. MySQL version is 5.6.17
6. Apache service test port 80 is not used.

I apologize in advance if my question seems difficult to understand but I will try my best to provide as much information as per request.

Comment: you told apache to listen on 127.0.0.1, and that's what it's doing. if you want to serve up your site on 175.162..., you'll have to tell apache to listen on that IP as well.

Comment: @MarcB I am quite confused what you meant. I set up Listen on 0.0.0.0:2727

Comment: but you also set the servername as an IP.

Comment: @MarcB The server name IP is my private ip address. That private ip address has also portforwarded the port 2727. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically WAMP and MySQL Community Edition does not work quite well together.
What I did was uninstall every program and files related to MySQL and WAMP. Restarted my PC and continue to delete existing folder related to both MySQL and WAMP.

Then, I installed a fresh WAMP again and it is finally green in color! Hooray!
So I head over to the **httpd.conf** file and edited **Listen 80** since it is the default and my ISP is not blocking port 80 and **ServerName 192.168.0.x:80** which is my Private IP address. I did not modify any other than this in the file and when I type my public ip by using my mobile data network, it connected successfully to my local website!

***Conclusion to set-up your own website ONLINE on your PC (with WAMP) :***

1. Obtain your private ip address (can be obtained from cmd by typing ipconfig)
2. Login to your router and port forward the port 80 (or another if your ISP is blocking port 80) under your **PRIVATE** ip address. Note : I port forwarded both TCP & UDP.
3. In Apache httpd.conf file, edit the Listen to your port number that you have port forwarded. **(Eg. Listen 80)**
4. Edit the **ServerName** below to **ServerName xxx.xxx.xx.xx:80** where the ip is your **private ip** address. If you use a different port, change the 80 to your own port.
5. And basically that is it! Type your public ip in your browser url and done! Note: If you use another port you will need to type in your port number as well **eg. 177.122.140.13:8080** (If port 8080 is what you chose)

Result :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Modify apache httpd.conf file

```
Listen 2727
```